# Using passport token in API select query

Tags: php, node.js, api, authentication

I am building an app using ExpressJS and NodeJS, and database for this application will be postgresql. Right now i'm actually stack on API part.

So i made a simple API in PHP, please look at the code below

```
    <?php

// Create connection
$con=new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=name;user=postgres;password=password');

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT totalscore, datestamp_app FROM tests";

// Check if there are results
//if (
$result = $con->query($sql);
//{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
//}

// Close connections
//pdo_close($con);
?>
```

So i'm able get a JSON with a data from SQL SELECT query

Perfect.

From the other site i'm able on my application get token for a users using passportJS (Google, Facebook, local tokens)

But my question is (and i'm really try to solve it last week) that should i do with this token regards Select query, as right now then API.php execute i get all data from tests table, put my goal is to get data only for concrete user with their token.

Any help will be really appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: you need a separate table for it. Where you can keep token and user id. When user request. they will send the token with request and than you have to authenticate it at php side. If it authenticated, you will process the request. Otherwise you will send back error response.

Comment: Great Abdul, thank you very much i get the idea! Maybe you can provide some code sample in PHP how to check user id  based on token during the request?

Comment: i am glad. you got the idea.